# Updating IP for port

Tags: linux, ip, raspberry-pi

In below unix output of `netstat -pln`, can the IP address 127.0.1.1 be changed to 0.0.0.0 for port 7077 via a unix command or is that determined by the process that is running on port 7077?

```
netstat -pln
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:7077          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2864/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2864/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:6066          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2864/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 192.168.192.22:123      0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21415           0.0.0.0:*                           -
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7195     -                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     405      -                   /run/udev/control
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; paste the *actual text*...

Comment: It depends on whatever is listening. 127.0.0.1 means it is listening on internal interface only. 0.0.0.0 means it is listening on any active interface. So if you can configure the listening port in whatever is listening you can probably set it to anything you like. So the important question is what exactly is listening on port 7077?

Comment: @wie5Ooma Apache Spark is listening on port 7077. But I'm unable to connect to it at this port. So it is the running process that determines what address it binds to, so I need to update Apache Spark process to listen at address 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.1.1 (I assume you mean 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.01 in your comment ?)

Comment: @wie5Ooma -p switch on netstat command?

Answer (score -1):

Basically when a process requests to open a TCP (or any other) socket in Linux it requests to listen on a specific port and specific IP. The simplest way to change the IP the process listens to, is just to let the process request a different IP to listen to. That means, that normally you change either the configuration of the application (e.g. by config files or by command line parameters), or if that is not possible, you need to recompile it.

To answer your question in a nutshell: Yes, the IP to listen to is specified by the process, not the operating system itself.

In general there might be possibilities to "hack the process" by and modifying its TCP handle. But that's for sure not the way to go...